# Call Modules Controller from Application Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-navigation, zend-application

I've asked a question like this previously but I believe this is different (that one was just a general question).

I implemented Zend_Navigation.

For menu I used DB Table to store menu items and did recursion on Array-s to get the tree of menu items.

All of this action takes place in my module called Menu. Inside I have:

```
Menu -- 
       Controllers --
                     IndexController.php
       Models--
               DbTable--
                        Menu.php
       Bootstrap.php
```

inside index controller I have a `function menuGenerator($menu_id)`

So following tutorials on Zend_Navigation, the menu is initialized in the application bootstrap.

my function inside application's bootstrap looks like this:

```
public function _initMenus() {

    $menuArray = new Menu_IndexController();
    $outArray = $menuArray->menuGenerator(1);

    $mainmenu = new Zend_Navigation($outArray);

    $this->view->navigation($mainmenu);     

}
```

and it gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Menu_IndexController' not found in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\project\application\Bootstrap.php on line 8
```

So, Any ideas how should I make it to work correctly?

P.S. is it possible to start 2 new menus at a time? for ex: I need 1. main menu 2. footer menu (any link to an article would be nice)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Zend Framework's autoloader doesn't autoload controllers in the same way it loads other components (models, view helpers, forms, etc), so PHP throws the error saying it can't find the class. The quickest way to get around this is to explicitly include the controller in Bootstrap.php. The following should work:

```
public function _initMenus() {

    require_once('./Controllers/IndexController.php');
    $menuArray = new Menu_IndexController();
    $outArray = $menuArray->menuGenerator(1);

    $mainmenu = new Zend_Navigation($outArray);

    $this->view->navigation($mainmenu);     

}
```

Comment: next error:  Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Controller_Action::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract, none given, called in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\project\application\Bootstrap.php on line 9 and defined in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\project\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php on line 127

Comment: Ah yes. Try instantiating the controller like this: $menuArray = new Menu_IndexController(
            new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple(),
            new Zend_Controller_Response_Http()
        );

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unusual to call a controller method *during* Bootstrap since there are many bootstrapping tasks upon which controller actions depend. In your case, the controller method `menuGenerator()` is not actually an *action*, so presumably it will not be a problem.

Nonetheless, it's still unusual enough that I would move the `menuGenerator()` method out into its own class. Then invoke that operation both at Bootstrap and in your controller.

Comment: Yeahm i know that in this case it's not an action. The thing is that I'm calling model to get array from DB, so you advise me to take it to my custom namespace library and load it from there?

Comment: Yep. Or in a service class inside `application/services/`. The key is to move the functionality to a place where both bootstrap and controller can easily invoke it.